# Angular testing: Mock base class

Tags: angular, typescript, mocking, jasmine, karma-runner

I want to test a certain component which extends a base class. The test for the component should be isolated from the BaseClass.

Is it possible to **mock the used base class** for testing? I tried to overide it by adding it to the providers override, but it didn't work out (normal base class still applied).

*my-component.page.ts*

```
import {Component, OnDestroy, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MyBaseClass} from '../my-base-class';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: 'my-component.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['my-component.page.scss']
})
export class MyComponentPage extends MyBaseClass implements OnInit, OnDestroy {}
```

*my.component.page.spec.ts*

```
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { MyComponentPage } from './my-component.page';

class MyBaseClassMock {}

describe('MyComponentPage', () => {
  let component: MyComponentPage;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponentPage>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MyComponentPage ],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
      providers: [{
          provide: MyBaseClass,
          useClass: MyBaseClassMock
        }]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponentPage);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Does someone have a idea how to mock a base class before creating a child instance? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The TestBed is to mock out things that are injected via the constructor and configure the various Angular modules; `extends` is [just JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends), you can't override that from the TestBed. Why do you want to isolate the class from its base in your test?

Comment: Okay thanks for clarifying that. I want to isolate it because it's base class is just some kind of helper which contains state management logic (not relevant for any tests). The component itself should be tested without further dependencies

Comment: Then you might want to rethink whether a base class is the appropriate way to add those helper methods (rather than a class you *can* inject via DI, for example). The base class is part of what your component *is*, it doesn't make sense to isolate it from that for testing.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible and also you do not want to do this. You want also unit test “base” class (because it is integral part of the component functionality and you also want to unit test this). If something should be isolated, it should be then a dependency of that class and injected via dependency injection.

We mock only injectable dependencies, this is how also test bed works. So please mock only your injectable dependencies.